# Are destructors of library types well defined?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, polymorphism, c++20

For example the `iterator` type - here I need to have a polymorphic iterator of different types depending on the usage. So I create a union with user defined constructor and destructor:

I'm specifically questioning the destructors names (eg. `~iterator()`).

```
#include <list>
#include <string>

struct val_origin {
    union {
        std::list<std::list<std::string>>::iterator iterenum;
        std::list<std::list<std::list<struct var>>>::iterator iterunorstr;
        std::list<struct var>::reverse_iterator vartypedef;
    };

    enum ORIG_ENUM {
        ORIG_ENUM_TYPE,
        ORIG_STRUC_TYPE,
        ORIG_TYPEDEF,
        ORIG_PLAIN
    } orig;

    val_origin(ORIG_ENUM orig) {
        switch (orig) if (0)
        case ORIG_ENUM_TYPE:
            new (&iterenum)decltype(iterenum) {};
        else if (0)
        case ORIG_STRUC_TYPE:
            new (&iterunorstr)decltype(iterunorstr) {};
        else if (0)
        case ORIG_TYPEDEF:
            new (&vartypedef)decltype(vartypedef) {};
    }

    val_origin& operator=(const val_origin& val_origin_in) {
        this->~val_origin();

        new (this)val_origin{ val_origin_in };
    }

    val_origin(const val_origin& val_origin) {
        switch (orig) if (0)
        case ORIG_ENUM_TYPE:
            iterenum = val_origin.iterenum;
        else if (0)
        case ORIG_STRUC_TYPE:
            iterunorstr = val_origin.iterunorstr;
        else if (0)
        case ORIG_TYPEDEF:
            vartypedef = val_origin.vartypedef;
    }

    ~val_origin() {
        switch (orig) if (0)
        case ORIG_ENUM_TYPE:
            iterenum.decltype(iterenum)::~iterator();
        else if (0)
        case ORIG_STRUC_TYPE:
            iterunorstr.decltype(iterunorstr)::~iterator();
        else if (0)
        case ORIG_TYPEDEF:
            vartypedef.decltype(vartypedef)::~reverse_iterator();
    }
};
```

Now my issue is that the above code compiles fine on [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/eT5bdjoMe). But when I switch to clang or  MSVC it fails.

My question is if this a standard code or not (would appreciate citation from the standard, I wasn't able to find the relevant info) and also if not what is my other option for implementing this.

I'm trying to have a dynamic (run-time) polymorphic iterator (same object but different type of iterators which will be used by different parts of the code appropriately).

The code fails on MSVC because the destructor name is not known.

Comment: You should use `std::variant` instead of reimplementing it.

Comment: What is this `switch (orig) if (0)` construct meant to accomplish?

Comment: @interjay It's a single statement switch. Definitely looking into `std::variant` right now - thanks.

Comment: Calling it "a single statement switch" doesn't explain what it's meant to accomplish. It's lots of noise for no apparent purpose. A `switch` statement **is** a single statement.

Comment: @pete maybe it's implicit breaks. Not sure whether explicit elses is all that better.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb -- well spotted. Still lots of noise. <g>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name lookup for destructors is very subtle to support things like **typedef-names** for non-class types.  There’s no guarantee, though, that `iterator` is available here since the iterator need not be a **class** type named `iterator` (or `reverse_iterator`) so as to provide that as an injected-class-name and since there’s no declaration for **unqualified** lookup to find.

Moreover, after recent clarifications the rule is that `decltype(…)::~…` is just invalid ([expr.prim.id.qual]/4).  Of course, there’s very little reason to **qualify** destructor “names” anyway: you can just write

```
iterenum.~decltype(iterenum)();
```

and so on.

Comment: Very impressive - is the is a new feature of C++20 perhaps? In any case the exact `iterenum.~decltype(iterenum)();` seems to be compiling under VC++2022 Preview.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions: I don’t think this has changed since `decltype` was introduced in C++11, although some specification bugs have been fixed at intervals.

Comment: I say this because it's not compiling with [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/7GnGxeWKo) it seems (it works fine with clang and msvc).

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions: I think that’s just a GCC bug; you can try introducing `using T=decltype(…);` and then write `x.T::~T();`.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably use C++ mechanisms (derived classes with the different alternatives) and not the --very low-level-- C `union`. You'd have to look at the generated code to check for runtime overhead, if any. I suspect this kind of unusual construction (a `union` of class objects) might confuse some compilers into generating incorrect code for (virtual or otherwise) method/field accesses.

Comment: Can you point to something specific in the code which isn't well-defined?

Comment: @interjay, no. But I'd be *very* vary of such code.